# Retrieve embeded image in Post, and display it in my App

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

As title, my goal is to display the images in user's Post on my iOS/Android App. 
Using below API:

GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups//threads//posts

Which only return the cid of the img.

How can I get information so I can display the image?
[image information example in RED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb1xz.jpg)

Thanks,
Raymond,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Base64 source, you can try to set the src property of the Image object like this :

```
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
 document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, but how do I get the information like Content-Type (image/png) and Encoding (base64)?

Comment: Found the answer, I can get information from attachments:http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get